# equivalant <html:messages> in thymeleaf for displaying messages

Tags: java, html, spring, jakarta-ee, thymeleaf

I am new to thymeleaf and converting some of ma code written in JSP+struts to Spring3 + thymeleaf. I have a this tag

```
<html:messages id="mymessage" property="mymessage" message="true" >
  //Some message here
</html:messages>
```

Can anyone tell me the equivalent tag or way to convert this code in thymeleaf??

Comment: What namespace is html?

Answer (score 1):

The Thymeleaf guide [covers messages in section 4](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Using-Thymeleaf.html#messages). Use `#{message.key}` as the value for any of the Thymeleaf HTML attributes, and `#{message.key(param1, param2)}` for parameterized messages.